# How can you discreetly advertise underground death matches?

Tags: secret-society, criminal-underworld

I, Rex Machismo, have determined that modern society has robbed this generation of its male identity. Gone are the days of conquerors, where we met each other on the field of battle with sword and shield for territory, only to be replaced by. millenials. A lazy and whiny generation, with their fancy pants lattes and avocado toast, these idiots love to blame society for their problems and insist that success be handed to them on a silver platter. They would rather talk about their feelings, feminism, political correctness, and the evils of "toxic masculinity". I roll my eyes at this drivel, which has made men  weak and pathetic.

The only solution to this problem is DEATHBATTLE, an underground fighting ring where various combatants can compete with each other 1v1 to restore their dignity and self-respect, all in glory to the blood god Khorne. Only by beating each other senseless in a death match can an individual restore their manhood and stand proudly among their peers again.

There are rules that members must follow:

1. **Don't talk about deathbattle**.
2. **DON'T TALK ABOUT DEATHBATTLE!!!**
3. Matches are only 1v1, where each fighter chooses a weapon before the match
4. Killing is allowed, but not preferred.

My ultimate goal is to create a chain of these undergound groups across the country, each devoted to the same cause. They must be advertised to certain enlightened individuals interested in participating, as well as those interested in being paying spectators in order for me to turn a profit. However, there is a problem with promoting these underground tournaments.

One cannot simply advertise on Facebook or Twitter the address of their nearest DEATHBATTLE. Word of mouth also breaks the rules, as one can never be sure of undercover cops and reporters trying to expose the ring. The final problem is for these competitions to stay true to their purpose.

How can I advertise this project without exposing it to the authorities?

Comment: If we are standing in a ring beating each other's brains in with melee weapons, what do we care if a bunch of millennial police recruits crash the party carrying handguns that they are afraid to fire.   The more the <strike>merrier</strike> bloodier!

Comment: This is really no different from how underground animal or street fighting operates in the real world. The difference is one of severity, not kind. You could research how those people manage it.

Comment: @TimB, the trouble is, they don't talk about it much

Comment: @Separatrix Plenty of other people do research it though for the purposes of shutting it down. It's not something I've ever looked into myself but I'd be surprised if there is nothing out there.

Comment: @HenryTaylor I’m sure we could have a posted shrink-wrap license, which all new age cops would read and respect, that entering the building (where the fights happen) constitutes full endorsement and intent to participate, thereby enable legally pounding the cops into dust if they enter. All hail the Amazon-Alibaba UN Treaty on licensing!  :-)

Comment: "_There are too many weak men! The solution is for strong men to murder or cripple other strong men, thus reducing the number of strong men!_" Someone, somewhere, has either not thought this through, or is being hilariously cunning.

Comment: If Rex chooses to lead by example and be first into the ring, then it's a self-solving problem.

Answer (score 6):

### Dirt for dirt

Surely, this kind of mindless violence will have a strong following by the more criminal members of society, no? And despite the interesting fourth rule of your DEATHBATTLE decrying murder, many of your participants may already have committed such an act. I say, let the heathens invite their ilk -- no one joins a DEATHBATTLE, gets to attend, or perhaps even learns of its existence without you, *Rex Machismo*, having some sort of evidence of their wrongdoings, as a sort of blackmail/collateral. Sort of like becoming a mafia member through murder -- you have to *prove* you're not a pig if you want to be a man.

Let the heretics invite each other, after first consulting you or your licensed DEATHRECRUITERS -- they know their kind well enough. Just make sure you have something stashed away on each of them so they know they can never squeal.

Answer (score 5):

**Act like a terrorist organization**

So, just to double-check, this is the literal plot of *Fight Club*, and what you're asking is, 'How do I discreetly advertise'?

Word of mouth, primarily. Honestly, it's really the best and safest way to avoid the ratfink stool pidgeons squealing on you. Have the people involved tell other people who are 'on the level' and so on and so forth. And then keep them all self-contained. If your motivation isn't money, but to combat people smack talking 'toxic masculinity' by creating it, all you need to do is start a self-propagating system. Make a small pamphlet, possibly creatively titled like 'The Complete Guide to Starting A Death Battle Club', and pick a few promising dudes, then send them out into cities so your underground fight ring is essentially now just a bunch of loosely connected cells, so even if a few get busted, the rest are safe.

Answer (score 3):

I would say - you can't.

Authorities wich do not know about any (including absolutly legal) activity, involving more than hundred of persons (even if it is GIVE-A-HUGS-BATTLE) are not true authorities.

It means DEATHBATTLE needs to be extreamely narrow circled (like very few rich people introducing there warriors for selfentatainment and bets) and/or requer highly corrupted authorities.

In fist case you do not need any advertise. And you have no problems with simple street advertising in second case (just do not do it too obvious).

Answer (score 3):

As with so many things that are officially against the rules, the only way to proceed is to get the authorities involved and give them their payola. Get the mayor on your side. Get the governor on your side. Get the chief of police on your side.

These can involve innovative means. For example: The chief of police may have a list of individuals he would rather were no longer bothering him. If these people were to be on the ticket of the next evening's entertainment, it would really make things easier for him. So, since you have at hand a bunch of people who know how to use weapons, and are willing to inflict damage, you go grab the people the COP dislikes. And they star in the next winner-take-all round-robin tournament. Single-loss-elimination rules as it were.

But mostly you would emphasize to the powers-that-be that the losses are small and undesirable people, and that they will be getting a metric tonne of money. And that if they don't agree the losers will show up on their lawn.

Answer (score 1):

> One cannot simply advertise on Facebook or Twitter the address of their nearest DEATHBATTLE.

Yeah, I was thinking about that. But then it dawned on me:

> yadda yadda **Rex Machismo** yadda yadda **modern society has robbed this generation of its male identity** yadda yadda **idiots love to blame society for their problems** yadda yadda **They would rather talk about their feelings, feminism, political correctness, and the evils of "toxic masculinity"** yadda yadda **made men weak and pathetic**.

Your whole target audience is made of incels, so don't waste money on advertising. Just go where they thrive (4Chan, some specific subreddits, and whatever network they went to after the new code of conduct was implemented here). You will find you'll quickly make friends with them, so you can get a few pinned posts there with the addresses for the upcoming battles. Just don't expect many people to participate, though, as the people who would be reading your calls for participation would be rather on the sedentary side of the spectrum.

---

If you really have a desire to see men kicking each other heads, why don't you just watch UFC/MMA?

Comment: Or you could use UFC/MMA matches as places to recruit people.  Send scouts to strike up conversations with spectators and fighters looking for people who "want something more".

Answer (score 0):

First get rid of the death aspect altogether. It alienates people too much. 
You can have a separate death tournament or something. The best of the best style. 
But normal death causes too much trouble.

Now to the structure of the organization.
The biggest issue is funds. Are you a mad billionaire who is funding this?
Or do you have to actually find a method of getting funds? 
Anyway I'll talk about general principles and talk about money later.
City cell is the answer. Each city works separately from the other with a city leader handling the affairs of the city. Cell leaders don't know each other at all.
No inter-city competitions or moving. Just separate city entities. 
Second the City leaders at first would report to a single person. 
Something like a state leader.
That state leader never meets them in the same place twice, never discusses other members of the cells with other members. 
Better yet if you grow big enough split the city 2 and have two different leaders state leaders. Same rules though. State leaders only meet alone with the person above them.
Orders are only given verbally and without anyone but the person giving the order and the person handling the situation. 
This is something like what the Godfather does.

Just think that at anytime a cell can be caught so what can you do to make sure that nothing more than that cell is comprised? 
Because even if a cell leader rats they only know one name and that is the person above them. But even then they have no means of implicating them in anything. 
And much like the proof of loyalty of the Mafia is killing someone. 
You will use the same principle. 
If someone wants to become a part of the organization then they must murder someone in cold blood, I think if a match is better as it shows strength, with their respective leader as the only witness. That remove the fear of anyone else ratting on the two others.

Anyway as you go up the chain of command the same logic should be applied.
Cold blooded murder. And, if possible, security checks.
Supplying the unfortunate souls should not be a problem. Just random violent criminals should keep you swimming in people to kill. 
The important part about recruitment is the screening process. 
You won't just let people off the street into your super secretive hideout. 
Generally you spread the word around anywhere. It won't matter.
Then you figure out a way of insuring the loyalty and the sincerity of the people trying to join. Here, again, a small criminal test is the answer. 
You only let people in after said person commits a certain crime, murder is too much so maybe something less sever but still totally illegal and can get them to jail, in the presence of the recruiter so again none of them can testify or cause trouble to the other.

As you grow and continually test the loyalty of the member then you can start accepting people only based on recommendations.
That is to be even accepted to be tested. 
You can still leave the door open to men with outside individuals with extraordinary abilities to join.

And word of mouth is actually very good for this sort of thing. 
Nothing concrete and for people serious enough to join it's enough. 
Gossip is a potent form of advertising.

You should also have in place a robust system once people are inside. Much like the Godfather. There you can be a cop then turn criminal and rise to become the Don's bodyguard. But there is a testing process involved.

Lastly. Much like fight club. You will start having a cult and people getting involved more and more. You can use the hardcore members for violence and external fighting, the state or local gangs or such, while still keeping a large pool of casual members. 
Developing a cult is a matter of money, charisma, and organization skills. 
Simple as that.

Now for extra fun. Bribery. Oh boy. The government, every single one, is susceptible to bribery and corruption. 
Having a cover of judges, officials, police captains, journalists and other media types...etc can be the difference between a terrorist group and just a harmless gentleman's club. 
With enough money and dirt work all those type can be in your pocket. 
Then Khorne would be pleased.

Comment: Welcome to the Worldbuilding Stack Exchange! I'm afraid answering a question by circumventing the question (in this case 'don't do a death-match') does not answer the question. Please revise your answer to better fit the question.

Comment: He can ditch that piece of advice of course. 
But I believe is still applicable

Comment: @ALambentEye This is called a frame challenge.  In WB.SE we generally allow such answers that "don't answer" the question directly as long as it supports why the question itself can not be realistically answered.  By saying "But normal death causes too much trouble." Seallussus is introducing the case that the OP only works if you don't make intentional killing part of the fight club.  That said, Seallussus, when doing a frame challenge you should provide some argument, reasoning, or evidence to support it.

Answer (score 0):

Word of mouth.  Best advertising for illegal activity then for insurance I was thinking along the bribery line as well.  Bribe the police but also ENLIST the police.  Death matches certainly will need more and more participants since you constantly lose 50% of your "athletes."  Who better to supply participants than the "underground" courts.  Why imprison criminals when you can quietly get rid of them at the Deathbattles!